# Photoswipe doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, photoswipe

I created a `jQuery mobile` page , where i import the albums and photos from a facebook page and dynamically create a listView with the albums. When the user clicks on an album from the listview he can see all the photos in thumbnails.

When he hits a photo he `should` see them in a nice carousel effect.

However in my case when i select a foto i just see the photo in the facebook link.

How it should be(click on a picture for carousel effect) :

[PhotoSwipe Example](http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html)

What i get after i select a picture :

[image]

I dont get the carousel effect..Instead i just get the image in the fb link.

This is all my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CityInfo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <link href="photoSwipe/jquery-mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="photoSwipe/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="photoSwipe/klass.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="photoSwipe/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //PhotoSwipe
        /*
         * IMPORTANT!!!
         * REMEMBER TO ADD  rel="external"  to your anchor tags. 
         * If you don't this will mess with how jQuery Mobile works
         */
        (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('div.gallery-page')
                    .on('pageshow', function(e){
                        var 
                            currentPage = $(e.target),
                            options = {},
                            photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.gallery a", e.target).photoSwipe(options,  currentPage.attr('id'));  
                        return true;    
                    })

                    .on('pagehide', function(e){
                        var 
                            currentPage = $(e.target),
                            photoSwipeInstance = PhotoSwipe.getInstance(currentPage.attr('id'));
                        if (typeof photoSwipeInstance != "undefined" && photoSwipeInstance != null) {
                            PhotoSwipe.detatch(photoSwipeInstance);
                        }
                        return true;    
                    }); 
            });
        }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
    </script>

</head> 

<body> 

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        var albumPhotos = new Array();
        var albumThumbnails = new Array();
        // start the entire process
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK 
            FB.init({
                appId      : '564984346887426',                    // App ID from the app dashboard
                channelUrl : 'channel.html',                       // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
            });

            FB.api('169070991963/albums', checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums));

        }


        // checkForErrorFirst wraps your function around the error checking code first
        // if there is no response, then your code will not be called
        // this allows you to just write the juicy working code 
        //   and not worry about error checking
        function checkForErrorFirst(myFunc) {
            return function(response) { 
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert("Noo!!");
                } else {
                    myFunc(response);
                }
            };
        }


        function getAlbums(response) {
            for (var i=0; i < response.data.length; ++i) {
                processAlbum(response.data[i], i);
            } 
        }


        function processAlbum(album, i) {
            FB.api(album.id + "/photos", checkForErrorFirst(populateAlbum(album, i)));
        }


        function populateAlbum(album, i) {
            return function(response) {
                for (var k=0; k < response.data.length; ++k){ 
                    albumThumbnails[i] =  albumThumbnails[i]||[];
                    albumThumbnails[i][k] = response.data[k].picture;
                    albumPhotos[i] = albumPhotos[i]||[];
                    albumPhotos[i][k] = response.data[k].source;
                }

                // now that we've populated the album thumbnails and photos, we can render the album
                FB.api(album.cover_photo, checkForErrorFirst(renderAlbum(album, i)));
            };
        }

        function renderAlbum(album, i) {
            return function(response) {
                var albumName = album.name;
                var albumCover = album.cover_photo;
                var albumId = album.id;
                var numberOfPhotos = album.count;

               // render photos
               $(".albums").append('<li>'+
               '<a href="#Gallery' + i + '"' + 'data-transition="slidedown">'+
               '<img src= "' + response.picture + '"  />'+
               '<h2>' + albumName + '</h2>'+
               '<p>' + "Number of Photos:  " + numberOfPhotos +'</p>'+
               '</a>'+
               '</li>').listview('refresh');

               $("#Home").after('<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id=Gallery'+ i +
               ' class="gallery-page"> ' +
               ' <div data-role="header"><h1>Gallery</h1></div> ' + ' <div data-role="content"> ' +
               ' <ul class="gallery"></ul> ' + ' </div> ' +
               ' </div> ');

               for(var x=0; x < albumPhotos[i].length; x++)
                    $('#Gallery' + i + ' .gallery').append('<li><a href="' + albumPhotos[i][x] 
                    + '"  rel="external"><img src="' +  albumThumbnails[i][x] + '"' + '/> </a> </li>');
             };
        }

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>



    <div data-role="page" id="Home" data-theme="c">
        <div data-role="content">
            <h2 id="banner" align = "center">Photo Albums</h2>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="albums">      
            </ul> 
        </div>      
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

As you see i call the fb Api to import albums and photos , i dynamically create the html page with jquery mobile depending on the number of albums and photos etc.

I cant understand what i am doing wrong here , as i try to follow the examples source code. The only difference is that instead of having the html page static ,  i create it dynamically. But i give it the correct form as far as i understand.

Any ideas on this one? (All the photos and albums are correctly imported , i have absolutely no problem with the facebook API. The only problem lies that i cant get the carousel effect from the library)

### EDIT

---

The only warning i get in the console is this :

**Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.**

However this is from the fb API (which by the way seems to work just fine...) and i dont think iτ has anything to do with the what i am trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the scripts responsible for handling the carrousel aren't available or are interrupted in a different line of code somewere that has an error: if you would strip out  jquery and the photoswipe js file reference from the header, the gallery would still have the same functionality as it has now due to css and markup.

Maybe good to rule out the obvious:
Did you check your links to the .js scripts?

I see that you use some with a http reference and others locally, if one of them aren't found the script will not work.

I'm quite new to java, my way of going at it would try to minimize the extra scripts around it and build it up from there.

Comment: This is all very good advice BUT , as far as i understand: 1) the scripts are ALL needed as they are in the example code too , 2) if one of the links to the .js files was wrong i would immediately see it in the console. As far as i am not getting any errors means that the scripts are all founded and loaded. 3) For what is worth mentioning i edit my question to include the only warning i get in the console. 4) Thank you very much for trying to help , really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting this run either. The website's documentation on how to use seems not elaborate enough...

EDIT: The interesting thing is that it seems to run in my desktop browser (the site demo) but not in my mobile browser (android/htc).

UPDATE: Funny. It doesn't run via apache2 as a website, but when I replace 'localhost' with '/var/ww' it is OK :)